# Select a Dropdown value in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium

I am working on automation with Selenium WebDriver. I need to select a dropdown value but I get an error report.

This is the code I am using:

```
 Select dropdown=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"myModal\"]/div/div/div/fieldset/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div/div[2]"))); 
Thread.sleep(30000);
dropdown.selectByIndex(2);
```

But I get this error: `Element should have been "select" but was "div"`

Comment: Add the relevant html. Select class only works with the select html tag. If you have a div or ul or li then you have to go old fashioned. Click on dropdown  then choose etc etc

Comment: could You provide html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will provide code with pageObject design

```
public class PageWithSelector{

    // initialise element first from element than to selector //
    @FindBy(id = "selectID")
    private WebElement selectorElement;
    private Select selector;

    public PageWithSelector(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        this.webDriver = driver;

        //in constructor init elements and also Select control//

        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        selector = new Select(selectorElement);
    }


     // selector via text //
    public PageWithSelector selectFromSelectorText(String selectorItemText){
        selector = new Select(selectorElement);
        selector.selectByVisibleText(facility.getName());
        return this;
    }

     // selector via index //    
   public PageWithSelector selectFromSelectorIndex(int index) {
        selector = new Select(selectorElement);
        selector.selectByIndex(index);
        return this;
    }

}
```

You have to only initialise Select (object) properly.

Answer (score 0):

After click on drop down you can use this code :

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(by.xpath(" your locator"));
for(WebElement element : options){
 if(element.getText().equals(" your value from drop down")){
    element.click();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I often use a workaround on that.
type inside the combobox the value you want to select and then automate an ENTER Keypress in the combobox.
Now the value is selected in the combobox.
Optional you also can use the Arrowkeys to navigate in the combobox.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("...")).sendKeys("Something you want to choose");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("...")).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("...")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Hope this helps!